# How to count length of each square (smaller matrix) in matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, implementation

I'm solving an algorithmic task with matrices involved.
I need to count each inner square (smaller matrix) inside a larger one.
Is there any dependencies between original length and each next?
As an example I have this matrix:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6
7  8  9  10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18 
19 20 21 22 23 24 
25 26 27 28 29 30
31 32 33 34 35 36
```

As you may see `Rows = 6`, `Cols = 6`, `Length = Rows * Cols;`

**Problem statement**: How to calculate the length of inner matrices:

```
8  9  10 11
14 15 16 17
20 21 22 23
26 27 28 29
```

And the last one

```
15 16
21 22
```

What I could do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){ 
    for(int j = 0; j < col; j++){
        //mirrored row and col e.g. 0 1 2 3 2 1 0
        int rowMir = i >= (int)Math.round(M/2.0d) ? (M - 1 - i) : i; 
        int colMir = j >= (int)Math.round(N/2.0d) ? (N - 1 - j) : j; 
        int depth = row > col ? col : row; //depth of inner square for each element in iteration. square's border in other words. 
        //In current matrix there are 3 inner squares (0, 1, 2)
    } 
}
```

Is it useful at all? I've tried to calculate it basing on values I've got, but no success until now. Googling gave me nothing in this case.

**EDIT**
The solution I'm looking for is to get size of the matrix for each element dynamically. Example for value at `[i][j]` I've counted the `depth`, the inner matrix it belongs to.

Comment: Is the original matrix always square (rows == columns)?

Comment: If the outer matrix is `6x6`, then according to your definition of inner matrices, their size would be `4x4` and `2x2`, i.e. size reduced by 2 on each side, for each inner matrix. No need to look at data. So, if original matrix was `13x10`, then inner matrices would be: `11x8`, `9x6`, `7x4`, and `5x2`, and lengths of all would be `130`, `88`, `54`, `28`, `10`.

Comment: So, if the starting matrix is 4x4, you want the sum of the number of elements of all the distinct 1x1, 2x2, and 3x3 regions inside?  Or does constructing an "inner" matrix mean keeping only elements not on the outer boundary?

Comment: @JeanLogeat, not always, it could be `6x5`, for example.

Comment: I'm afraid I can find no correlation between "problem statement" and displayed code. What is `M` and `N`? Why is `depth` calculated over and over when `row` and `col` never changes? What is purpose of the two loops? `rowMir` and `colMir` will calculate to numbers 0-2, so they will never be the `4x4` shown as first inner matrix in problem statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply decrease by a step of `2` at each iteration:

```
int minDim = Math.min(rows, columns);
for(int i = minDim ; i >= 0 ; i -= 2) {
    System.out.println("Inner length: " + ((rows - i) * (columns - i)))
}
```

Comment: Since you're assuming that original matrix may not be square (and I concur), why are you then assuming inner matrices have to be? Just decrease both `rows` and `columns` by 2 for each iteration, until one of them gets below 1.

Comment: @Andreas, isn't that equivalent to what he *is* doing?

Comment: In the loop below I've shower that it is needed for `each element` while looping. So it should be something like `(R - depth) * (C - depth)`. for element `[i][j]`, but somehow it doesn't give me the correct answer

Comment: @Yurets Well what is correct answer? From "problem statement" it would appear to be `16` and `4`, i.e. the lengths of the two matrices your shown. Is that the answer you're looking for? Please clarify question if not that.

Comment: Damn, I've tested your solution. It works. Somehow I've missed it. In my case I use already found `depth`, multiply it by 2 and the same. Thank you. I accept your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you actually want to print all the inner matrices and get the count then you can do something like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    /* Define Matrix */
    int matrixSize = 6;
    int[][] matrix = new int[][]{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
                                 {7, 8, 9, 10,11,12},
                                 {13,14,15,16,17,18},
                                 {19,20,21,22,23,24},
                                 {25,26,27,28,29,30},
                                 {31,32,33,34,35,36}};

    /* Initialize Count Counter */
    int count = 0;

    /* Count/Print Inner Matrices */                             
    for(int x = 2; x < matrixSize; x++) {
        for(int i = 0; i <= matrixSize - x; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j <= matrixSize - x; j++) {
                /* Call Print Matrix Function */
                printMatrix(matrix, i, j, x);
                ++count; /* Increment Counter */
            }
        }
    }

    /* Print Actual Count */
    System.out.println("\nTotal Inner Square Matrices Count: " + count);
}

/**
 * Print Matrix
 * Arguments: Matrix, Row Index, Column Index, Matrix Size
**/
public static void printMatrix(int[][] matrix, int i, int j, int size) {
    System.out.println();
    /* Row Iterator */
    for(int iIndex = i; iIndex < i + size; iIndex++) {
        System.out.println();
        /* Column Iterator */
        for(int jIndex = j; jIndex < j + size; jIndex++) {
            System.out.print(" " + matrix[iIndex][jIndex]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 2
7 8

2 3
8 9

...

Total Inner Matrices: 54
```